# How to set value in MUI Select on onChange in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I was facing some challenges while integrating `Formik` with the `Select` component of MUI, firstly, it didn't change the value on the `onChange` event and also was not showing any error messages , if I didn't select anything, so at last, I was able to find the solution and I have shared the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Here, I am setting the value directly using `formik.setFieldValue`  and passing the value to as we usually do, also to show error messages I have used `FormHelperText` from MUI

```js
 const formik = useFormik({
      initialValues: {
         user: '',
      },
      validationSchema: validationSchema,
      onSubmit: (values) => {
         alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      },
   });

------------


 <FormControl
               fullWidth
               size="small"
               id="userType"
               error={formik.touched.userType && Boolean(formik.errors.userType)}
            >
               <InputLabel id="user-type">User Type</InputLabel>
               <Select
                  id="userType"
                  label="User Type"
                  name="userType"
                  value={formik.values.userType}
                  onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                  onChange={(e) => formik.setFieldValue('userType', e.target.value as string)}
                  error={formik.touched.userType && Boolean(formik.errors.userType)}
               >
                  <MenuItem value={'admin'}>Student</MenuItem>
                  <MenuItem value={'superAdmin'}>Recruiter</MenuItem>
               </Select>
               {formik.touched.password && (
                  <FormHelperText sx={{ color: 'error.main' }}>{formik.errors.userType}</FormHelperText>
               )}
            </FormControl>
```